# Unable to register crpe32.dll using regsvr32

Tags: vba, windows, vb.net, dll, crystal-reports

I encountered Error 20728-F in VB project for Crystal report.

Installed Crystal report on my PC, I can read the crystal report by double click on .rpt file. DB used **Microsoft access database** and crystl32.ocx
My issue is more or less similar to this
https://www.toolbox.com/tech/programming/question/visual-basic-6-run-time-error-20728-f-when-call-crystal-report-020814/

After various searches found out that I need to add **crpe32.dll and dwmapi.dll.**

was able to register dwmapi.dll
Not able to register crpe32.dll now.
tried both on Windows/System32 and Windows/SysWOW64

[image]

I'm on windows 10. Tried a lot of options like giving permission to type registry etc none worked.

Downloaded dll file from various sites nothing worked out.

Any help appreciated

Comment: The error just means crpe32.dll is not a COM dll, maybe it's needed, but it's not registerable. As for dwmapi.dll, it's a Windows system dll, you shouldn't touch this, if it wasn't working, Windows wouldn't work either.  You can only install CR using CR's setup, not trying to tweak things manually. Maybe it's an x86 vs x64 issue. Did you install CR for both bitness, etc. or ask vendor directly

Answer (score -2):

Dynamic link loader is missing. Probably a corrupt file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you please be more clear. the DLL is downloaded from proper source.